# Half transparent circle in another half circle

Tags: css, geometry

I have to make such contruction like this one on the picture. There is a bubble with some fancy ending and I don't know, how to make this half transparent circle inside it.
How can I do that?
I have some image as a background.

```css
.bubble {
  background-color: #34bc74;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 15px 65px 25px 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #34bc74;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 140px;
  border-top-right-radius: 140px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -70px;
  right: -70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle:after {
    height: 70px;
    width: 35px;
    left: -35px;
    z-index: 2;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    // border: 35px solid $green;
    // box-shadow: 0px 300px 0px 300px #448CCB;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
  Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: why make a css shape, why not just use a background image (you can apply multiple to the same element)?

Comment: how? I have that, but how to make transparent circle inside?

Comment: you can do that kind of things with `clip-path` and a SVG, ask google for it, but as far as i recall, it isn't supported by every browser yet. As @pete suggested, you should probably use an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try create the shape using `svg` masking.

[Here's some more info from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking)

(poor) example...

```css
body {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/1000x1000);
}

.bubble {
  background-color: #34bc74;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 15px 65px 25px 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.bubble svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: -4em;
  top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
  Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id
  <svg width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <mask id="inner-circle">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="28" cx="40" cy="20" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="curve" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#34bc74" mask="url(#inner-circle)" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `pseudo-elements` and `box-shadow` properties you can get close to the intended result.
Experiment and adjust `height`, `width`, and `box-shadow` values as required.

```css
.bubble {
  background-color: #34bc74;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 15px 65px 25px 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.circle {
  width: 155px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: -45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  width: 112px;
  height: 87px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 55px -15px 0 0 #34bc74;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle:before {
  content: "";
  width: 112px;
  height: 88px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 72px 52px 0 0 #34bc74;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
  Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id Donec viverra sodales imperdiet. Aliquam eget ante nec nulla hendrerit dignissim sit amet id
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```